# TUploadFile: crash while uploading video file which is picked from the library

Tags: ios, quickblox

My application crashes when user try to upload a video to Quickblox server, after picking the video from the library. The same method works flawlessly if we try to upload an image or video captured from the camera. Thoughts?

**Environment details**

```
"QB-SDK" = "iOS 2.2.2";
"QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
```

**Did this work before?**

Yes

**Expected behavior**

Video should upload successfully, or an error should be returned.

**Actual behavior**

Application crash.

**Logs**

```
json: {"blob":{"name":"video","content_type":"video\/quicktime"}}
Request URL:https://api.quickblox.com/blobs.json
Request method: POST
Request parameters:{
    blob =     {
        "content_type" = "video/quicktime";
        name = video;
    };
}

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType _enableCropOverlayIfNecessary]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcd54526650'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105745d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108f3bdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010574ed3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105694cfa ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001056948a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   PhotoLibrary                        0x000000011f852a50 -[PLVideoRemaker _exportCompletedWithSuccess:] + 135
    6   AssetsLibraryServices               0x0000000115768709 __pl_dispatch_async_block_invoke + 25
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a837d9d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a8583eb _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010a8401ef _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010569f0f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105660b99 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001056600f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010afaead2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010754bf09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    15  MyApp               0x00000001043cc85f main + 111
    16  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a88d92d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

**Steps to reproduce the behavior**

Call the upload method for video that is picked from the library:

```
+ (QBRequest *)TUploadFile:(NSData*)data
                  fileName:(NSString*)fileName
               contentType:(NSString*)contentType
                  isPublic:(BOOL)isPublic
              successBlock:(void(^)(QBResponse *response, QBCBlob* blob))successBlock
               statusBlock:(QBRequestStatusUpdateBlock)statusBlock
                errorBlock:(void(^)(QBResponse *response))errorBlock;
```

Comment: You are using very old sdk. I can see the current version is 2.7.2. What about updating the SDK?

Comment: Looked into it. Many methods are now deprecated, so the effort required is more than we can handle at the moment. But, we definitely need to update the SDK.